# What is the time limit for reporting CoC violations? Can past violations be reported?

Tags: support, code-of-conduct

A few years back I got attacked by someone with privileges that first vandalized (i.e. changed content to something quite different) one reply I wrote and then apparently with the help of a few friends downvoted it to oblivion and the answer was finally deleted by a moderator for reasons that I felt were unjustified.

Reading now about the change in the Code of Conduct I noticed there is a "Disruptive use of tooling" section that was not previously there, and I wondered what the time limit for reporting CoC violations is.
I'm not as active on SO as I was long ago, but it's a bad memory I'd like to resolve if possible.

Comment: it'd be kinda silly to retroactively take action against every infraction that ever occured in the past that at the time wasn't a coc violation but is now.

Comment: Okay, the comments have gone *way* off the topic of the specific question that was asked regarding the time limit.  I've removed all discussion that is not about that and edited the question to focus on that question.  If you want to discuss whether the specific action taken was a CoC violation, either raise a flag for moderator attention or create a new meta post for that question specifically.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### There is no time limit on reporting CoC violations, but the age of a violation may affect moderator action

For example, if a violation occurred years ago, and the user has conducted themself well since, the moderators may choose, at their discretion, to either reduce something that would otherwise incur a suspension to a warning, or to simply note the behavior for the record in case it recurs in the future (we can annotate accounts without sending a message, in order to leave notes for moderators handling future cases involving the user).

For the specific case of something that was not previously a violation, but is now, we would still want to handle it and ensure that any problematic content is removed, problematic changes reversed, etc.  We wouldn't intentionally impose consequences beyond a warning for something that was not a violation of any rule at the time (but note that there are rules that exist outside of the Code of Conduct; one change in the new Code of Conduct is to try to have more of the rules in one place).

---

<sup>I'm not opining, for the record, on whether the given example describes a CoC violation, but simply answering the question about time limits.</sup>

Comment: Could a case that's nearly ___4___ years old really result in warnings? That seems like a slippery slope...

Comment: there's no real value in deciding how many arbitrary time units is long enough for no warning to occur

Comment: @Cerbrus It depends on the reason. Purely hypothetically, if we discovered horrible racist rants that somehow escaped detection for four years (unlikely!), that would certainly result in _at least_ a warning, and likely more. In other cases, the warning is more of a "heads up that we removed this; don't do it again, but we know it was old so there's no penalty." I think the most common reason we send warnings for old behavior is targeted voting. It serves as both warning and explanation; otherwise, the user may be confused by the rep change. It also allows the user to appeal by replying.

Comment: I think Ryan explained the relevant rule. The relevant practice is that if the violation is years old, then the mod will nearly always just silently delete, and there will be no retorsion. On the other side, I often suspect, but I have no way to know it, that some of the surprisingly harsh mod actions against me were caused by my old, long deleted content, which is now unavailable even for me.

Comment: @peterh If you're referring to the fact that suspensions often increase in length for repeatedly violating the same rule _after being warned not to_, then yes, that is a thing that we do, because we expect people to stop breaking the rules after being asked to do so.